# How to reset scroll on route changes in ember 3?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember.js-3

I'm trying to use hook activate, didTransition, or willTransition, but none of these work, they do nothing at all.
I try to start by one route:

```js
// app/routes/section.js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default class SectionRoute extends Route { 
  ...

  activate() { scroll(0, 0); }
}
```

```html
<!-- app/templates/section.hbs -->
<h1>{{model.title}}</h1>
<p>{{model.body}}</p>
{{outlet}}
{{#each model.subsections as |s| }}
  <Section @section={{s}} />
{{/each}}
```

This works in my js browser console:

```js
scroll(0, 0);
```

This is my router

```js
// app/router.js
...
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('docs');
  this.route('section', { path: '/docs/section/:slug' });
});
```

If I make section a child of docs, it works, as long as I don't hide parent's content, but I want to hide it.
An anchor in link-to component could help.

**When I remove this piece of css, it works.**

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: Does `activate` run at all? Like, does a `console.log` print? Are you truly navigating between routes or is just the model changing? For `didTransition` and `willTransition`, did you use them as actions? https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.20/classes/Route/events/didTransition?anchor=didTransition

Comment: Yes, it runs with `alert();` Yes, I'm navigating among routes. Yes, I used `didTransition` and `willTransition` as actions.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is working as expected. I have created an Ember Twiddle to verify that one, which you can find [here](https://ember-twiddle.com/2c2bccd9cab7df633ee4fc9c7b9a1e19?openFiles=routes.top%5C.js%2C&route=%2Ftop). It has two routes. One which scrolls to the top when activated and one which scrolls to bottom when activated. It's scrolling as expected.

I guess you may be facing issues with the hook if transitioning between subroutes? A route is considered to stay active and the activate hook is *not* called

- if a transition does not change the route but only the dynamic segments or query parameters used for the route or
- if a transition happens between subroutes of that route.

If you want to have scroll to top on every transition or want to have more granular control, which transitions should trigger that scrolling I would recommend to use [`routeDidChange` event of `RouterService`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.20/classes/RouterService/events/routeDidChange?anchor=routeDidChange) instead.

Comment: I've got the same problem with  routeDidChange event of RouterService.

Comment: Something must be wrong your your code. The approach is working as demonstrated by the Ember Twiddle. Maybe there is another `window.scroll()` fired with conflicting arguments in parallel? Maybe an element is focused, which triggers a scroll? So many options.

Comment: Your twiddle works. But if I write to the template, it is no longer working when I click it from not a parent route.

Comment: What do you mean by writing to the template?

Comment: I mean writing in route section template, which I want to scroll.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't follow. Can you please provide an Ember Twiddle demonstrating your issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219360/discussion-between-chiara-ani-and-jelhan).